# How could I load my own java classes into javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I need to have ability of using my own java classes in JS, but I don't know how to do it, since I'm newbie in JS. So how could I do it?

Comment: Please describe the runtime environment more clearly and what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these.

[DWR (Direct Web Remoting)](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

[GWT (Google Web Toolkit)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

See this guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html

Answer (score 0):

Java and JavaScript really have very little in common, which is why it's officially been renamed ECMAScript. You can use cross compilers to do some of the work for you (GWT compiles Java into JavaScript) but really they're two very different things in different idioms. I'm assuming here you're talking about client side browser JavaScript. It has been used in server side implementations for whacky hijynx.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of NodeJS, but I'd hardly describe it as "whacky hijynx".

Comment: @KirkWoll I like my beer cold and my languages strongly typed ;)

Comment: Me too, but there's no reason to start a flamewar with the enormous number of programmers who feel otherwise.

Comment: @KirkWoll I didn't say I hated it :) No flame intended.